# SQL Server 2008 - Enumerate multiple date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I enumerate multiple date ranges in SQL Server 2008? I know how to do this if my table contains a single record

```
StartDate   EndDate
2014-01-01  2014-01-03

;WITH DateRange
AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, [Date])
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
    )
SELECT * FROM DateRange
```

OUTPUT

```
2014-01-01, 2014-01-02, 2014-01-03
```

I am however lost as how to do it if my table contains multiple records. I could possibly use the above logic in a cursor but want to know if there is a set based solution instead.

```
StartDate    EndDate
2014-01-01   2014-01-03
2014-01-05   2014-01-06
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
2014-01-01, 2014-01-02, 2014-01-03, 2014-01-05, 2014-01-06
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!
(and that way, you don't need any of those messy `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` tags, either!)

Comment: Odd... every time I try to post an answer, I encounter an error from StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jon what is "an error"? What error?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've tried posting the same answer (saved to a file and copy/pasted each time) multiple times over the past hour.  Each time I try, it "thinks" for a while, and then I get a red box stating "An error occurred submitting the answer".

Comment: @Jon ah, that helpful error. *shrug* Sorry, when SO doesn't want to be helpful, we can't be any more helpful either. :-) If this is persistent, I'd raise the issue [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I finally managed to get my answer posted by adding it piece-meal until I found what part caused the failure.  Apparently it doesn't like "UNION-ALL" (without the dash, I can't even post it here).  I will post the issue on meta.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jon I have never seen a problem with UNION ALL. Perhaps you have some browser add-in or userscript that is messing with you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm using Chrome with no extensions or userscripts.  It's interesting that you can post that but I cannot.

Comment: @Jon http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185836/165455

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's see.  Define the ranges as a table.  Then generate the full range of dates from the first to the last date.  Finally, select the dates that are in the range:

```
with dateranges as (
      select cast('2014-01-01' as date) as StartDate, cast('2014-01-03' as date) as EndDate union all
      select '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06'
     ),
     _dates as (
      SELECT min(StartDate) AS [Date], max(EndDate) as enddate
      FROM dateranges
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, [Date]), enddate
      FROM _dates
      WHERE [Date] < enddate
     ),
     dates as (
      select [date]
      from _dates d
      where exists (select 1 from dateranges dr where d.[date] >= dr.startdate and d.[date] <= dr.enddate)
    )
select *
from dates 
. . .
```

You can see this work [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14729).

Comment: Your idea is sound, but your SQL does not run.  You mixed up several of your references to your CTE's (such as _dates referencing dates, which comes after; and dates referencing itself when it's not meant to be recursive).  Your join syntax is also invalid in SQL Server, as it is missing an "ON" clause.

Comment: @Jon I agree the idea is sound, but it's certainly not working. Makes you wonder why people accept answers they couldn't possibly have even tried.

Comment: @JonSenchyna . . . The idea was ok.  The syntax was abyssmal.  The solution now works.  I assume it was accepted based on the idea.  Essentially, the code was psuedo-code, rather than actual running code.  Now it works, though.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - I never tried Gordon Linoff's code. I read the first two lines where he described the solution and it was all I needed to get my code working.

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the min and max dates first, like so:

```
SELECT @startDate = MIN(StartDate), @endDate = MAX(EndDate)
FROM YourTable
WHERE ...
```

And then pass those variables into your date range enumerator.

*Edit...* Whoops, I missed an important requirement. See the accepted answer.

Comment: I could but then 2014-01-04 would show up in the table when it is not a part of either range. Your answer is partially correct as shown by @Gordon Linoff. The missing piece is the final select where I omit dates not in the ranges.

Comment: @user1 My mistake, I missed that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As GordonLinoff mentioned, you should:

1. Store your ranges in a table
2. Generate a range of dates that encompasses your ranges
3. Filter down to only those dates that fall within the range

The following query builds up a collection of numbers, and then uses that to quickly generate all of the dates that fall within each range.

```
-- Create a table of digits (0-9)
DECLARE @Digits TABLE (digit INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @Digits(digit)
VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
WITH
-- Store our ranges in a common table expression
CTE_DateRanges(StartDate, EndDate)  AS  (
    SELECT  '2014-01-01', '2014-01-03'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06'
)

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, NUMBERS.num, RANGES.StartDate) AS Date
FROM
(
    -- Create the list of all 3-digit numbers (0-999)
    SELECT D3.digit * 100 + D2.digit * 10 + D1.digit AS num
    FROM @Digits AS D1
    CROSS JOIN @Digits AS D2
    CROSS JOIN @Digits AS D3
    -- Add more CROSS JOINs to @Digits if your ranges span more than 999 days
)   NUMBERS
-- Join to our ranges table to generate the dates and filter them
-- down to those that fall within a range
INNER JOIN  CTE_DateRanges  RANGES
    ON  DATEADD(DAY, NUMBERS.num, RANGES.StartDate) <= RANGES.EndDate
ORDER   BY
        Date
```

The date creation is done by joining our number list with our date ranges, using the number as a number of days to add to the `StartDate` of the range.  We then filter out any results where the generated date for a given range falls beyond that range's `EndDate`.  Since we're adding a non-negative number of days to the `StartDate` to generate the date, we know that our date will always be greater-than-or-equal-to the `StartDate` of the range, so we don't need to include `StartDate` in the `WHERE` clause.

This query will return `DATETIME` values.  If you need a `DATE` value, rather than a `DATETIME` value, you can simply cast the value in the `SELECT` clause.

Credit goes to [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658145) for the digits table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for editing this for me.  It looks like a case of this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185681/unable-to-post-any-answer-or-comment-with-union-all

Comment: Yeah our comments crossed paths (see above).